# How to copy records from remote SQL Server 2005 to local mySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, copy

Guys, how to copy View records from REMOTE SQL Server 2005 to a Table on LOCAL mySQL using PHP?

from the View (REMOTE SQL Server 2005) : select * from source_View
 
Fields : username, firstname, lastname, email, nik

into (local mySQL) : select * from target_table
Fields : username, firstname, lastname, email, idnumber

Please help, thank you..

Comment: one time only or scheduled? ODBC-access? migrating tool if so, if not, I'd script with php/xml.

Comment: Scheduled, that's why I have to use a batch file that runs a PHP script

Answer (score 0):

This will not work as you cannot have an SQL statement that processes records from two different hosts in one go. Why don't you just get sql dump of the table and import it using MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I need to do it automatically on scheduler. That's why I have to use a batch file to run a PHP script to copy the records.